# How can I quickly remove duplicates from a list box?

Tags: delphi, listbox, duplicates

I wish to remove duplicate items from a large TListBox. To do that I use a classic simple method. It works, but it takes 19 minutes. I read a lot and apparently I should use a TFileStream (?). But I don't know how.

My classic method is this:

```
procedure NoDup(AListBox : TListBox);
var
  i : integer;
begin
  with AListBox do
  for i := Items.Count - 1 downto 0 do
  begin
    if Items.IndexOf(Items[i]) < i then
    Items.Delete(i);
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
end;
```

How can I improve the speed?

Comment: Adding a BeginUpdate/EndUpdate pair would speed it up, but you shouldn't really look for duplicates yourself, see my answer

Comment: The best approach is probably to avoid putting duplicates into the list control in the first place. And if there are really so many that it takes 19 minutes to process, you probably have too many to be presenting to a user without filtering anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. Yes, I would have preferred that the duplicates was controled before but "it's not possible". Finally I chose the solution below by Daniel. Works like a charm ! Best from France :)

Comment: Beny, where did you read that TFileStream would help?

Comment: The time it takes for your code partly depends on the number of duplicates because of the `Application.ProcessMessages` calls. In effect, you're telling you wanna *see* every item removed. The call is made for every iteration but most of them will return rather quick if there's no item removal, still it also is unnecessary time spent. Removing it together with Begin/EndUpdate as Daniel said should make a remarkable difference.

Comment: I didn't know the Begin/EndUpdate. It's really interesting !
@Rob : I can't remember where I read that TFileStream would help... But the process was different (RichEdit to ListBox (...)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
procedure NoDup(AListBox: TListBox);
var
  lStringList: TStringList;
begin
  lStringList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    lStringList.Duplicates := dupIgnore;
    lStringList.Sorted := true;
    lStringList.Assign(AListBox.Items);
    AListBox.Items.Assign(lStringList);
  finally
    lStringList.free
  end;
end;
```

Comment: One word : **THANK YOU** ! Just perfect ! With my previous function time was 19 minutes. With your function time is around 1 minute. I tried to use StringList but without success. Simple code but really great :)

Comment: Beny, please note that this method changes the order of the remaining items, assuming they weren't sorted to begin with.